# When I have Azure do a CloudBlockBlob.StartCopyAsync(), is there a way to have it verify a checksum?

Tags: azure-blob-storage

When I initiate an async copy of a block blob to another storage account using `StartCopyAsync`, is Azure doing any kind of integrity check for me, or if not, is there a way to have it do so?

I found that I can set the `Properties.ContentMD5` property and have the integrity verified when uploading blobs. Is it also verifying during a copy operation?

I searched through the docs and found no mention of an integrity check during an async copy specifically. I found a couple references to AzCopy making integrity checks, and it also has the `/CheckMD5` option, which is essentially what I'd like Azure to do after the blob copy.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the azure blob SDK is the package of the azure blob rest api.

So the azure SDK StartCopyAsync method will use [copy operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob)(rest api) send to the azure server side to tell the server copy.

According to the copy operation [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob#remarks), you could find "When a blob is copied, the following system properties are copied to the destination blob with the same values".

It contains the "Content-MD5" property.

Comment: You are correct, it does copy that. What I'm wondering is if the system does anything on it's part to make sure the new copied blob matches the copied md5?

Comment: The MD5 is not validated, but there are other integrity checks in place.  Data corruption in the copy shouldn't be a concern, and as long as the Content-MD5 header on the source blob is correct, the header on the destination blob should also be correct.  Note, however, that it is possible to set the Content-MD5 header on a blob to whatever you want - the Storage Service doesn't validate that it's correct when using PutBlockList, and if it's incorrect, this value will still be copied to the new blob.